# Github actions on push and on pull_request difference

Tags: github-actions

on push and on pull_request difference in github actions?

On every pull request we are pushing our code then why do we need on push and on pull_request isn't just on push enough?

Answer (score 16):

You can trigger only on pushes to master or pull requests to master. This will prevent builds from happening twice when somebody opens a pull request against master and then pushes updates to their branch.

For example:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - master
```

Answer (score 9):

> on push and on pull_request difference in github actions?

In general, `push` will trigger when you push code where `pull_request` will trigger when there is a pull request.

They overlap when you create PRs from the same repo, but you need `pull_request` if you want to run an action when you receive a PR from a fork for example. You need `push` when you want to run an action when something is push. You can fine tune them depending on the behaviour you expect to avoid duplication of jobs.

Comment: The only duplication I can think of is when somebody (*cough* dependabot *cough*) pushes a single commit and opens a PR with it against master. Then the same build is run twice. But I can't figure out how to "fine tune" my triggers to avoid this without also turning off builds I'd like to run.

Answer (score 2):

Example that highlights the difference and shows that both can be important and needed:

Imagine you want to run CI tests every time code is `pushed`, but **only when in a PR** (eg to save money in GHA)

If you only use `on: push` then when the PR is first raised, you won't have any tests run (because raising a PR alone does not trigger the `on: push`)
You also need `on: pull_request`