# Github workflow dorny-filter changes succeeds on branch push, but fails on PR merge

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to detect changes in github workflow using dorny filter:

```
name: Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main
      - release
        
jobs:
  changes:
    name: Detect changes
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      clouds-provider: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.clouds-provider }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
        id: filter
        with:
          filters: |
            clouds-provider:
              - 'aws/**'
              - 'azure/**'
              - 'gcp/**'
```

When I push aws/azure/gcp changes directly to the branch it works great: `changes.output.clouds-provider = true`

However using the same changes, when I try PR merge it will fail to recognize the changes: `changes.output.clouds-provider = false`, but it should be true.

Comment: I'm new to github actions.  All of my github actions have an `'on'` block at the top of them that indicates therein for which github actions I want to have the action run.  My first and only thought is that maybe you need an `on:  pull_request:` somewhere.

Comment: Yes thank you, I didn't think it was necessary to post that portion, but I will include it

Comment: Ok, great.  So I can see now that you have `push:` but not `pull_request:`.  I would think that would be the explanation for your problem.  I wonder if this question might be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70767090/github-actions-on-push-and-on-pull-request-difference

Comment: PR merged is the same as ```push```, and as proof the workflow would run in both scenerio. However the problem that I am facing is why it has different results?

Comment: Ah, ok.  As I said, I'm new to github actions, and so I had a feeling I was maybe barking up the wrong tree.  Just figured it couldn't hurt to mention it.